# Setting environment variables in OS X /etc/launchd.conf

Tags: mac, macos, osx-snow-leopard, environment-variables, launchd

I'm trying to set some env variable in OS X 10.6 (/etc/launchd.conf)

```
setenv M2_HOME /usr/share/maven
setenv M2 $M2_HOME/bin
setenv MAVEN_OPTS '-Xms256m -Xmx512m'
```

M2 and MAVEN_OPTS are not working.

I tried with something like

```
setenv MAVEN_OPTS -Xms256m\ -Xmx512m
```

but still it doesn't work. Any idea of what is the correct synthax?
Thanks

Comment: Shouldnt this all be going in a `plist` for loading with `launchctl`?

Comment: Do you mean environment.plist? I refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x it says 'environment.plist does not work for applications launched via Spotlight' so I was trying to set the env variables using launchd.conf. It works fine. But It won't work using spaces or if I concat variables using $

Comment: @al nik: no not environment.plist. i mean a plist to use with Maven as a service - if youre trying to run this as a background service (daemon) then you should be crafting your own plist to launch the daemon and this data would go there. I see from your response below that youre trying to get this var hooked up in IntelliJ instead im guessing? If thats so then i would look for a way to set variables withing IntelliJ. I dont know if it provides this but i know Eclipse does so i would assume there is something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/share/maven
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export MAVEN_OPTS='-Xms256m -Xmx512m'
```

Comment: it won't work http://www.digitaledgesw.com/node/31

Answer (score 1):

While I realize that there are many ways to go about this. If one is just interested in configuring environment variables for IntelliJ then you could do the following without going through a lot of hassle:

**IntelliJIDEA -> Preferences -> Path Variables**

Now select Add on the right and add your required variables. In my case it is the following as I used homebrew to install Maven:

```
Name: M2_HOME
Value: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4
```

Now look under **IntelliJIDEA -> Preferences -> Maven** and everything should be automatically configured. Select OK and now you should be all set. Just so you guys know I use IntelliJ IDEA 11.

Be advised that the above will work only in IntelliJ. If you want this in terminal, put the required stuff in .bash_profile or throw it in /etc/launchd.conf if you want this for GUI's and the terminal. You can find more info on these methods easily doing a quick search.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this answer helps after all this time. You find a solution along your lines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x/3756686). I think your problem is that the stuff in the third row, like **$M2_HOME/bin** or **'-Xms256m -Xmx512m'**, is not expanded before it gets fed to *launchctl*. I provided another solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/476752/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x-for-gui-applications).