# Setting environment variables in OS X for GUI applications

Tags: macos, environment-variables, launchd, launchctl

How does one set up environment variables in Mac OS X such that they are available for GUI applications without using [~/.MacOSX/environment.plist](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html) or *Login Hooks* (since these are [deprecated](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CustomLogin.html))?

Comment: @ersin-er The answer from StackOverflow ["Solution for both command line and GUI apps from a single source (works with Yosemite & El Capitan)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x/32405815#32405815) may be of interest to people finding this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution uses the functionality of `launchctl`, combined with a *Launch Agent* to mimic the login hooks of old. For other solutions using the store of `launchd`, see [this comparison](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/64917/30415).
The launch agent used here is located in */Library/LaunchAgents/*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>user.conf.launchd</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/Shared/conflaunchd.sh</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>~/.conf.launchd</string>
    </array>
    <key>EnableGlobbing</key>
    <true/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
    <array>
        <string>Aqua</string>
        <string>StandardIO</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

One important thing is the *RunAtLoad* key so that the launch agent is executed at the earliest time possible.
The real work is done in the shell script */Users/Shared/conflaunchd.sh*, which reads *~/.conf.launchd* and feeds it to `launchctl`:

```
#! /bin/bash

#filename="$1"
filename="$HOME/.conf.launchd"

if [ ! -r "$filename" ]; then
    exit
fi

eval $(/usr/libexec/path_helper -s)

while read line; do
    # skip lines that only contain whitespace or a comment
    if [ ! -n "$line" -o `expr "$line" : '#'` -gt 0 ]; then continue; fi

    eval launchctl $line
done <"$filename"

exit 0
```

Notice the call of `path_helper` to get **PATH** set up right. Finally, *~/.conf.launchd* looks like that

```
setenv PATH ~/Applications:"${PATH}"

setenv TEXINPUTS .:~/Documents/texmf//:
setenv BIBINPUTS .:~/Documents/texmf/bibtex//:
setenv BSTINPUTS .:~/Documents/texmf/bibtex//:

# Locale
setenv LANG en_US.UTF-8
```

These are `launchctl` commands, see its manpage for further information. Works fine for me (I should mention that I'm still a Snow Leopard guy), GUI applications such as *texstudio* and *TeXShop* can see my own tex tree. Things that can be improved:

1. The shell script has a `#filename="$1"` in it. This is not accidental, as the file name should be feeded to the script by the launch agent as an argument, but that doesn't work.
2. As mentioned [here](https://www.heise.de/artikel-archiv/ct/2012/19/154_Mac-OS-X-Automatische-Firewall-Blockade) (German and behind a paywall!), it is possible to put the script in the launch agent itsself.
3. I am not sure how secure this solution is, as it uses `eval` with user provided strings.
4. I think to remember that the definition of MANPATH using this method didn't work well, but I'm not sure.

It should be mentioned that Apple intended a somewhat similar approach by putting stuff in *∼/launchd.conf*, but it is currently unsupported as to this date and OS (see the manpage of `launchd.conf`). I guess that things like globbing would not work as they do in this proposal. And of course one can put these files anywhere else, except the launch agent which must reside in */Library/LaunchAgents/* or *~/Library/LaunchAgents/*.

Finally, I should mention the sources I used as information on Launch Agents:
[1](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html), [2](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2083/_index.html), [3](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.25/25.10/2510MacEnterprise-SnowLeopard-launchdandLunch/index.html), [4](http://web.archive.org/web/20110707092748/http://www.afp548.com/article.php?story=20050620071558293).

*Update*: This does not work in version 10.8 at the moment. Workarounds on a per application basis are described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/65880/30415) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/51737/30415).

Comment: By the way, if one wants to define the PATH-Variable in a Terminal environment and uses this launch agent, I suggest to write `export PATH=.:"$(launchctl getenv PATH)"` in ~/.bash_profile (similarly for other shells). This is possible since `path_helper` is called in the shell script. For more details on the PATH variable in OS X, check [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/284351/160019).

Answer (score 23):

On Mountain Lion all the `/etc/paths` and `/etc/launchd.conf` editing doesn't take any effect!

Apple's Developer Forums say:

> "Change the Info.plist of the .app itself to contain an "LSEnvironment"
>   dictionary with the environment variables you want.
>
> ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist is no longer supported."

So I directly edited the app's `Info.plist` (right click on "AppName.app" (in this case SourceTree) and then "`Show package contents`")

[image: Show Package Contents]

and added a new key/dict pair called:

```
<key>LSEnvironment</key>
<dict>
     <key>PATH</key>
     <string>/Users/flori/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin:/Users/flori/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/bin:/Users/flori/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p326/bin:/Users/flori/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:</string>
</dict>
```

(see: [LaunchServicesKeys Documentation at Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html))

[image]

now the App (in my case SourceTree) uses the given path and works with git 1.9.3 :-)

PS: Of course you have to adjust the Path entry to your specific path needs.

Comment: Thank you!  This was perfect for me.  On 10.11 (El Capitan) I did have to also run [the commands provided by Matthew](https://superuser.com/a/787415/583200) in order to see my changes to `Info.plist` take effect.

Answer (score 5):

The answer provided by @flori works for me on Maverick provided I run the following commands in Terminal after changing the plist file

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user 

killall Finder
```

Comment: I had the same behavior with El Capitan, and I have added your point to @flori's answer

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by @percival-ulysses works for me on 10.9 Mavericks with the following small change: edit */Users/Shared/conflaunchd.sh* script right before `exit 0` and add the lines

```
killall Dock
killall SystemUIServer
```

to restart the Dock and the menubar. After this the applications started from the Dock or from Spotlight will inherit the correct PATH.  If you use Finder to start the PATH-critical applications, then `killall Finder` may be added too.

In the `.bash_profile` I use the line

```
export PATH=`launchctl getenv PATH`
```

to set the PATH for the Terminal, this way the PATH is controlled from the same location, the *~/.conf.launchd* file.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `/etc/launchd.conf`. For example I have changed the default `PATH` by adding this line to `/etc/launchd.conf`:

```
setenv PATH ~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/libexec:/usr/texbin
```

You can apply changes to `/etc/launchd.conf` by either restarting, or by running `launchctl < /etc/launchd.conf; sudo launchctl < /etc/launchd.conf` and terminating and relaunching processes.

Settings in `/etc/launchd.conf` apply to both the root launchd process and per-user launchd processes. Environment variables set with `setenv` in `/etc/launchd.conf` are shown by both `sudo launchctl export` and `launchctl export`.