# Environment variables only work if I launch the application from terminal

Tags: macos, environment-variables

I recently got a MacBook and I'm doing some programming with Eclipse. I need to use Amazon S3, so I needed to set my credentials as environment variables. 
I typed `vim ~/bash_profile` and added the following lines:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXX
```

Then, I saved the changes, typed `source ~/.bash_profile`, and restarted my computer.

If I open Eclipse by clicking the icon, then Eclipse can't find the environment variables; but if I open it using the terminal, then Eclipse sees the variables and my code runs fine.

Why is that happening and how can I solve it?

Btw, I'm using High Sierra (10.13.6)

Comment: https://www.schrodinger.com/kb/1842

Comment: Exact duplicate ( easily found the *"Related** side bar ) [Launch mac eclipse with environment variables set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829749/launch-mac-eclipse-with-environment-variables-set?rq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch mac eclipse with environment variables set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829749/launch-mac-eclipse-with-environment-variables-set)

Answer (score -1):

Eclipse supports setting the environment variables in a few ways.  I would follow the instructions on their [product website that describes the process](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_run_env.htm).

Also, refer to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/476752/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x-for-gui-applications) from @flori on Superuser which describes a means with graphics.

Another way is to navigate to the Eclipse Dir and edit the Info.plist file in ./Eclipse.app/Contents/Info.plist.